# TvOS Simulator keyboard stopped working?

Tags: tvos

Does anyone know how to fix a problem where the TvOS simulator stops accepting keyboard input? I use the arrow keys to navigate the simulator and move focus around and it was working fine until yesterday.  I tried deleting the simulator and removed and reinstalled Xcode, did a clean pull of the code that works fine on my iMac from github and the keyboard still doesn't send events to text fields and navigation doesn't work with the arrow keys.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry - this was easy to resolve.    Go to Hardware menu and select Keyboard->Connect Hardware Keyboard.  I must have tried to do clean build of the app using a keyboard shortcut which is Shift-Command-Option-K and Connect Hardware Keyboard has a very similar key command to toggle which is Shift-Command-K.

Answer (score 1):

I my case the keyboard stopped working *partially*, since iOS 13.4. In that version the implementation of `pressesBegan` has been changed, you must call `super` for all unhandled key presses, otherwise even arrow keys won't be handled anymore.

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {

    if press.type == .playPause { // Or whatever
        // Do your thing
        return
    }

    // Call this for all unhandled key presses
    super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
}
```